# How to get DSM data for C# projects with Sonarqube 5.x

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

I don't know if this is related to [SONAR-6176](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6176) but I am trying to get DSM data for a .net solution, containing five projects.  Normally our build process puts all the binaries under the ./target folder within the solution folder like so:

```
+-Solution Dir
  +-target
    +-APIProj
    |   APIProj.dll
    +-ImplProj
       APIProj.dll
       ImplProj.dll

      and so forth...
```

Initially during analysis, I was getting warning that the binaries could not be found, but I fixed that setting `sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths=Solution Dir/target/**`.  Now I get appropriate log output that states "Using the following assembly for..."  However, after analysis, I still get the "No DSM data available for the component" message in the UI.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Note: this is with SonarQube 5.0 and C# Plugin 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that this was indeed an instance of [SOANR-6176](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6176).  All design related metrics are being dropped anyway. See [SONAR-6553](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553).